# gem install fails when building an image on Docker for Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, ssl, docker, bundler

I'm trying to build a Docker image from a Dockerfile. The image is based on the latest [node:alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) image. It installs Ruby and a few gems on top of it. Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine
ENV BUNDLE_SILENCE_ROOT_WARNING=1 BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=/usr/local/bundle \
  BUNDLE_BIN=/usr/local/bundle/bin BUNDLE_PATH=/usr/local/bundle
RUN apk add ruby ruby-io-console ruby-bundler ca-certificates \
  build-base ruby-dev ruby-json libffi-dev \
  python zlib-dev --no-cache && \
  update-ca-certificates

WORKDIR /opt/middleman
COPY Gemfile* ./
RUN bundle install --clean
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
```

I can build the image on Linux and MacOS, but on Windows bundler fails randomly, on a different gem every time, with the following message:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A (https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-2.0.1.gem)
```

I've googled the SSL error and most solutions suggest installing some SSL certificates. However, in my case the base Docker image is the same. Only the Docker host OS is different. And if the problem were the SSL certs, bundler would always fail on the first gem not a random one each time. So my guess is there's something wrong when Docker runs on Windows, but I have run out of ideas. Any help?

PS: I've made sure that all machines have the same snapshot of node:alpine which happens to be this:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
node                alpine              37434f668ea8        30 hours ago        55.3 MB
```

---

### Update:

1. I also tried building the [quick-start Rails image](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/) and it fails.
2. I tried building the quick-start image with the older Docker Toolbox which uses VirtualBox instead of Hyper-V. It failed again, each time on a different gem, but the error is now different:

   ```
   Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/gems/minitest-5.10.1.gem)
   ```

Still an SSL error, though.

Comment: Use  http version instead of https, for example "gem install rails --source http://rubygems.org"

Comment: Nice workaround! I changed the Gemfile's source to http and it worked! However, I still don't understand what the underlying issue with SSL is.

Comment: The official [docker rails tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/) does not work either. It fails with the same SSL error.

Comment: If one gem fails to install due to SSL errors then they all should fail.  Try "gem update --system" before installing any gems.

Comment: @JLB you are right, however every time I try to build the image, a different gem fails. This was never an issue on macOS or Linux, so I'm guessing it's either an issue with Docker for Windows, or HyperV, or Windows itself. By the way, I did try `gem update --system` and it does nothing. Says `Latest version currently installed. Aborting.` and again bundler fails randomly.

Comment: I have it running on multiple Windows machines (64 bit Ruby), plus Docker on Windows (under HyperV).  Though you will find plenty of people who have had a similar issue, it does usually work.  Try "gem update" and then "gem cleanup".  Also, you could try getting it running under the official Bash for Windows (not Cygwin) as a prelim for building a Docker image.

Comment: Here is my working dockerfile http://dpaste.com/3V0K3JV

Comment: @JLB thanks, but it was caused by a completely unrelated setting... See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your comments. I finally found the culprit. It's a "feature" of my Killer Wireless card... For future reference, I had to disable "Advanced Stream Detect" in the "Killer Network Manager" app. Here's a screenshot:

[image: SSL Killer]

They should probably call it SSL killer.